# Unable to install Fedora linux along with my Windows 11 on my Asus vivobook

Tags: linux

I was trying to install Fedora along with my Windows 11 on my Asus vivobook by dual boot. But I could not do it successfully. I saw various posts and videos and changed my SATA configuration to AHCI but still the Fedora installer could not identify my hard-disk.

Please help me with installing Fedora or sharing links on how to do so.

Thanks :)

Comment: New laptops are unlikely to have any HDD in the first place; they tend to have SSDs instead, often NVMe SSDs. A NVMe SSD is effectively a PCIe card with a differently-shaped connector, and does not have anything to do with SATA. Make sure the `nvme` driver is loaded, and be aware that the NVMe device names are not like `/dev/sdX`, but typically the whole device is `/dev/nvmeNn1` (N=number) and partitions are `/dev/nvmeNn1pX` (X=partition number).

Comment: Was it Fedora 36? Please try running any Fedora Live version, e.g. https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ and upload the result of this command (Open Terminal and paste:) `dmesg > ~/Desktop/dmesg.txt` anywhere you want. The Live version supports WiFi and has a web browser, so it mustn't be an issue. @telcoM the nvme driver absolutely must load by default. NVMe disks have been supported for ages out of the box without any tinkering.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I just thought that some OEM NVMe with a strange PCI ID might escape the autodetection... it would be a very slim chance and a mistake from the NVMe manufacturer.

Comment: I've seen such bugs on bugzilla.kernel.org - this is precisely why I asked for `dmesg`. But it's not about the `nvme` driver not loading, it's about certain NVMe's drives not conforming to standards.